# Can't install module from CPAN

Tags: perl, cpan

First time using CPAN trying to get module. Why can't i install?

```
cpan[9]> install GD::Graph
Running install for module 'GD::Graph'
Running make for R/RU/RUZ/GDGraph-1.48.tar.gz
Prepending blib/arch and blib/lib of 18 build dirs to PERL5LIB; for 'get'
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /root/.cpan/build/GDGraph-1.48-LBF9mR
Prepending blib/arch and blib/lib of 18 build dirs to PERL5LIB; for 'make'
  '/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site' returned status 512, won't make
Prepending blib/arch and blib/lib of 18 build dirs to PERL5LIB; for 'test'
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install
```

After manual install i got this:

```
...
Installing /usr/local/share/man/man3/Graph::Matrix.3pm
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
ERROR: Can't create '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/Graph'
mkdir /usr/local/lib64/perl5: File exists at /usr/share/perl5/ExtUtils/Install.pm      line   483
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 at -e line 1
make: *** [pure_site_install] Error 17
```

Comment: Try installing it manually (`tar xvzf GDGraph-1.48.tar.gz; cd foo; perl Makefile.PL; make; make test; make install;`) and look at the error messages (which will probably tell you that a c library you are depending on is missing).

Comment: @Quentin, thx. After manual install i got message in the updated post.

Comment: @sliddy Did you try `sudo make install`?

Comment: If you're asking about two different problems, we'll need to see the error message of the first, either by forcing `make` (not install) or by setting `cpan`'s `build_dir_reuse` to `0`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, i'm root, why i need sudo?

Comment: @ikegami, I couldn't install module through CPAN, so after Quentin's advice i did everything he said and updated post with error i got after **make install** command. It is the same question, i just want to know why i can't install module.

Comment: That's the part I answered. You didn't show you can't install through CPAN (since your `build_dir_reuse` got changed to true), but it's probably the same reason you're seeing without using `cpan`: That you are unable to create dir `/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/Graph`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to create dir `Graph` in `/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto`, but you don't have permission to do so.

Comment: I'm root, how could i don't have permission to do that?

Comment: A read-only mount? Well, it could be another error, such as the drive being full or `/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/Graph` already existing as something other than a directory. Much more likely that it's not running as root.

Comment: As you said, its something other than a directory. Just renamed the perl5 file and everything passed fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Another avenue to try is the Perl Package Manager.**

1. In windows, you search on Perl and it will list appropriate
   "programs"...
2. Select the Perl Package Manager.
3. Then inside the package manager, I search GD::Graph and it gives
   four choices.
4. I installed GDGraph-XY.
5. Then I did a "use GD::Graph;" inside a .pl and it ran fine.

Comment: But the paths in this question make it pretty clear that we're talking about Linux or Unix here.

Comment: Perl Package Manager doesn't come with Linux or Unix installation? I would think the concept would be similar.

Comment: PPM is part of ActivePerl. You'll get installed if that's what you're using. But very few people on Linux/Unix (and a decreasing number on Windows) use ActivePerl. A Linux distribution will have its own packaging facility (e.g. yum on Red Hat-based systems or apt on Debian-based systems) but they work really differently to PPM.

Comment: Thanks Dave.. Curious... what do you see Windows Perl programmers using? Strawberry Perl?

Comment: Yeah, Strawberry Perl seems very popular. Largely, I think, because it includes everything you need to get a CPAN toolchain running - thereby freeing people from relying on PPM.